# Trying to create a bot using Java and having the bot read something that's already on screen into the program

Tags: java, input, bots

Is it possible in java to read something that's on the screen into the program, such as a specific line on the screen? Say I need the program to get some numbers that are on a website and depending on the numbers it'll perform a specific task, is there a way to have the program scan and get input from a specific website?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.
For example using test framework Selenium Webdriver.
It has embedded Firefox driver.
So you only need to add this framework to your project, create an instance of Firefox driver, enter URL of your site, then using xPath/ID/CSS path, get values you need and process them.
To search for xPath use Firebug , load your site in FF, right click on the element, inspect in Firebug, right click on the element -> get xPath

Answer (score 0):

Java can make Screenshots. If you use OCR text recognition you can then extract texts.

However usually you access the sources directly (for example use java to receive a html page, instead of reading text from screen output of a browser).